# How can I use simple in a camel choice component when the message is in XML format?

Tags: java, jaxb, apache-camel

I have the following statement in camel:

```
      <setProperty propertyName="REASON_FOR_CHANGE"><simple>${body.header.EventName} + ' ' + ${body.header.RolledbackEvent}</simple></setProperty>
```

I am receiving an error along these lines when that statement is reached in the camel route:

```
  org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed to invoke method: .header.EventName on null due to: org.apache.camel.language.bean.RuntimeBeanExpressionException: Failed to invoke method: header on null due to: org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException: Method with name: header not found on bean: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Event>
<Header>
<EventName>Foo</EventName>
<RolledbackEvent>Bar</RolledbackEvent>
<Action>XFR</Action>
<Effective>2015-01-26T00:00:00.000</Effective>
</Header>
<Message>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<LastName>Doe</LastName>
</Message>
</Event>
```

I found this link while googling: https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=36754

My understanding from that link is that my data is in the incorrect format for Simple to process and that Simple doesn't understand XML.

I'd greatly prefer not having to use XPath, and I already have annotated JAXB classes for this XML object.  The XML can be deserialized and reserialized in the custom processors.

Is manual type conversion sometimes required when using different expression languages?  I understand some cases like CSV processing that would have to be true, but for different object notation languages too?

Is there a way to make camel do type conversion of the xml to a java object for the purpose of using Simple or is there a better expression language for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `bodyAs(type)` function in simple you may try to use, to convert the body to your POJO class. You would need to type in the FQN class name.